# Where to get "idf" coef for words?

Tags: database, search, full-text-search, search-engine

I want to calculate [tf-idf weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf). So, for finding idf I need big database of different documents. Then I have make other db with colums-(word/count).
So my question is "where can I find last database of "idf" (or count) coef for words"?
Many search engines are using this db, maybe it is possible find this db in Internet for different languages?
I don't want to make this db by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

idf is Inverse Document Frequency. In other words, the frequency of the term goes in the denominator. So what you want are word frequency tables. [Wiktionary:Frequency lists](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aFrequency_lists) should get you started. Keep in mind these lists treat inflected forms of a word as the same word e.g. be, is, am, are, ....